# Magento Free shipping and Coupon discount

Tags: php, magento

I have a free shipping price rule which is configured like this:

- All customer groups
- No coupon
- uses per customer: 0
- Conditions: Cart total >= 100, Shipping country == NL or BE or DE
- Free shipment: for shipment with matching items.

When I enter a coupon with a fixed discount amount however, the free shipment disappears.

Both price rules have Stop Further Rule Processing set to NO

This behaviour of Magento is driving me insane

Comment: I didn't understand. You were set `No Coupon` in rules but you are trying to enter a coupon code. How is it possible?

Comment: There is a second price rule with a coupon which gives a 15 euro discount, but when I enter this one the free shipping disappears, even though the total order value is still over 100

Comment: Yes, the subtotal is over 100

Comment: If your coupon code rule has "Free shipping: No" then its behaving the way that it's supposed to.  Why not combine the conditions in the Shopping Cart Price Rules?  Set up both conditions and use "ANY" instead of "ALL" and group your rules together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Magento does not care about other shopping cart price rules if there is a valid coupon code entered in the Front-end.

Fix for this issue is in the comments of the following website:
http://magentoexpert.com/issue-with-cart-price-rules-coupon-code-discard-promotion-without-coupon-code/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in one of the comments it's best that you try and convert the current rule into a "**Shopping Cart Price Rule**".

In a Shopping Cart Price rule you can also set conditions that depend on the subtotal of the cart, the shipping region, shipping country, ...

In the action tab you can easily **Free shipping option** to **"For shipment with matching items"**

This should solve it ;)

Comment: This would mean I would have to set the Free Shipping option for every coupon code (which will be a lot), that's just not viable for my client

Answer (score 0):

- Go through all your other rules which might be triggered as well (make sure they have "further rule processing" on "no").
- Set the priority to "1"

Try again if the rule is applied and let us know.

Comment: There are no more rules which can be applied, setting the priority had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking for Magento CE 1.9 and above, the code is corrected as long as the database is concerned but you might encounter the same problem! If so, then there is another cause.

One also usual bug is * user not being able to update the cart quantities* or *users not able to login*. This has to do with formKey and the answer that was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915093/magento-quantity-in-checkout-shopping-cart-dont-work-properly).

Apparently, **the same solution fixes the problem** of vanished shipment or payment method after applying a coupon, that we are discussing here.

Hope this helps users of newer versions...

so be it - manemoi