# Magento free shipping coupon breaking other coupons (and itself)

Tags: magento

Magento free shipping coupon breaking other coupons (and itself)

MAGE 1.6.1 Comm

Our problem is as follows. when I enter a free shipping coupon code it actually kills all aready entered codes and doesnt show shipping discount either

Try it at http://shirtsofholland.com, order 1 item

enter coupon: FBKORTING01 (5 euro discount) + after that PICKUP (no shipping cost)

This is the setup of the PICKUP coupon

[image]

In the end we would like to offer coupons with different kind of coupons 5%, 5 euro, etc ... and when people in addition want to pickup the order they receive a second discount that triggers the shipping costs discount

Thx for any help

PS. I read this, but it doesnt solve it. [Magento Free shipping and Coupon discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680951/magento-free-shipping-and-coupon-discount)

I do think this is a bug so reported to Mage

> Impossible to setup two usable coupons: 1 with 10$ discount and 1 with
>   free shipping
>
> Hi, we have the following.
>
> 1 coupon gives free shipping (priority 10), further rules YES: coupon
>   code PICKUP 1 coupon gives 10$ discount (priority 20), further rules
>   NO: coupon code 10OFF 1 coupon gives 5% discount (priority 50),
>   further rules NO: no code, triggered by value
>
> If I enter 10OFF, followed by PICKUP the result is; 5% discount and
>   free shipping (not the expected 10OFF and free shipping)
>
> I would expect the system to use the PICKUP coupon first with lowest
>   prio 10, then continue processing us yes, so it moves to the 10OFF
>   coupon code with prio 20, and then stop because further rules
>   processing is NO
>
> What is going on? This is very urgent for us. And as I now have been
>   playing with this for two days and read all the forums - I am logging
>   this issue. Please fix in 1.7
>
> Also read this: People having the same:
>   http://magentoexpert.com/issue-with-cart-price-rules-coupon-code-discard-promotion-without-coupon-code/

Comment: Hmmmm/ No idea. Free shipping is just causing troubles

Comment: Apparently others have this also: http://www.magentocommerce.com/answers/When-applying-shopping-cart-price-rules-free-shipping-wont-apply-if-coupon-code-is-present