# Magento. Quantity in checkout shopping cart doesn't work properly

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento 1.8.0 and on localhost the cart is working correctly.
I change the quantity of a product in the cart then I push the "Update cart" button and all works fine. 
I trasferred the site online and the cart quantity doesn't work anymore.
As I change the quantity of a product and click the button the quantity remains the same. If I go back and try to add the same product to the cart, even if I specify a different quantity like 10 and not 1, in the cart only 1 item is added every time I click on "add to the cart" button and not 10 as specified.
I cannot figure out where's the problem. I excluded my custom theme and rolled back to the default theme and the problem persist.
I updated magento to 1.8.1 and the same problem.

Answer (score 21):

In your theme directory

In your /app/design/frontend/yourthemepackage/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml file or /app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml file

Just place on line 50 just after getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post"> paste the below code

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

it will work fine now.

P.S. for more information you can check same answer on http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/11/shopping-cart-quantity-not-able-to.html

Answer (score 5):

Those who have upgraded their Magento to 1.8 must have following line in

app\design\frontend\default\customtheme\template\checkout\cart.phtml

```
  <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>  // this line must be there
```

Answer (score 4):

It was a combination of two settings (System > Configuration > Web).

Change from:

**Unsecure**

- Base URL: `http://domain.name/`
- Base Link URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}media/`
- Base JavaScript URL: `{{unsecure_base_url}}js/`

**Secure**

- Base URL: `https://domain.name/`
- Base Link URL: `{{secure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL: `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL: `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
- Base JavaScript URL: `{{secure_base_url}}js/`
- Use Secure URLs in Frontend: `YES`
- Use Secure URLs in Admin: `YES`

to :

**Unsecure**

- Base URL: `https://domain.name/`
- Base Link URL: `{{secure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL: `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL: `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
- Base JavaScript URL: `{{secure_base_url}}js/`

**Secure**

- Base URL: `https://domain.name/`
- Base Link URL: `{{secure_base_url}}`
- Base Skin URL: `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`
- Base Media URL: `{{secure_base_url}}media/`
- Base JavaScript URL: `{{secure_base_url}}js/`
- Use Secure URLs in Frontend: `YES`
- Use Secure URLs in Admin: `YES`

And, finally, do not forget to add this:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

at **line 57** in file *../template/checkout/cart.phtml*
The second setting works for **Magento 1.8.1**.
I'm pretty sure that for **Magento 1.8.0**, the first setting for my domain hosted on secure HTTPS protocol would be sufficient.
It seems weird but it seems that the cookies used by the cart have problems when using the first site configuration.
Or maybe it's a redirect issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass form key in cart.phtml file to solve this issue.

app\design\frontend\yourpackage\yourtheme\template\checkout\cart.phtml

You can pass form key by

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

after form tag.

It will be like

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Or before submit button in same file

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" >
```